# enable sticky edges in GNOME

Tags: gnome, display

I installed gnome-shell and ubuntu-gnome-desktop on an existing lubuntu installation.

Is it possible, on GNOME shell, to enable sticky edges, as on Unity, for multiple displays?

Comment: Sorry, but what are sticky edges?

Comment: Which version of ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @NonnyMoose sticky edges are a unity thing for dual monitors where your mouse hangs before entering the next monitor, better for pressing buttons on the side.

Comment: @Anwar it is xenial xerus on this one